# Rails : Undefined Method in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following code in my model for a method to check if a particular email address exists for a branch:

```
def does_email_exist(email, branch_id)
    if Person.for_branch(branch_id).where(:email => email).count == 0
        return true
    else 
        return false
    end
end
```

However, when I call it from the Rails Console, I get the following error :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `does_email_exist' for #<Class:0x007fdcb9fb8ab8>from 
/Users/mkv/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
```

I have reloaded the console after adding the method.

Comment: How are you calling that method on the console?

Comment: could you add the line that's calling this method?

Comment: I was trying Person.does_email_exsit(email, branch_id). I'm curious to also know whether this is the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do though

Answer (score 1):

This seems more like a class method than an instance method, try renaming your method to

```
def self.does_email_exist(email, branch_id)
  Person.for_branch(branch_id).where(email: email).exists?
end
```

And yea I trimmed the method a bit, didn't need to be that long.

Comment: This is not going to change anything. Self is used when you want to call a mutator.

Comment: well idk, i'm just assuming the call is something like `Peroson.does_email_exist` .. i've asked for the line that's calling the method and i'll update the answer when the OP answers